# Is it more efficient to specify a specific path in require instead of destructuring?

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I've run into an interesting conversation with a co-worker, in some libraries' documentation you can still find instructions to import them like this:

```
const a = require('b/a');
```

However, I usually use destructuring like this:

```
const { a } = require('b');
```

The question is: which of the methods is less efficient. According to my logic node will have to analyze the file in both to get access to a specific function anyway so there isn't any difference efficiency-wise. Am I correct?

Comment: If we're talking *efficiency*, then the first one should be better. You are *explicitly* asking only for `b/a`. If you instead destructure, you're asking for *the entire* `b`, which includes `b.a`, `b.b`, `b.c`, ...`b.n` and then only plucking one thing out of it. There could be optimisation techniques to remove the overhead of asking for everything but since the former is explicit, it doesn't need those.

Comment: So the node require module can access a specific function without analyzing the entire file of 'b'? If I try to oversimplify it, it will open the file 'b' and just look for the string "function a" there?

Comment: Depends on how the module is setup. But *usually* you have one `b` which just collects all of `b/a`, `b/b`, `b/c`, ...`b/n` and serves them as a single bundle. So, `{ a } = require('b')` will have to require that entire bundle and then only extract `b.a` from it. It's like doing `temp = require('b'); a = b.a` - you still get the entire thing. As I said, some optimisation techniques may realise you only need `b/a` and don't include the rest but that's a separate matter.

Comment: No. It means to execute everything inside and then return module.exports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way require it works is simple. It goes to the file specified and executes everything and then **returns** the **module.exports** for the "module" that called the require for the first time and caches its response for the next subsequent call.

So in your case let's assume that you are calling  *b.js*

```
//b.js
const a = require ('a')
const c = require ('c')

module.exports = {a,c}
```

*b.js*, *a.js* and *c.js* will be executed.

Or you could do only and directly require *a.js*;

```
//a.js
//no requires
const a = someFunction();
modules.exports = a;
```

In that simple case it is obvious a call to **"a"** module it would be faster. But that assuming you are only using the *a* module of the dependency you are installing and *that is almost never the case*. Either way if calling the library entirely it will be cached throughout your application and subsequent calls would be faster.
So it's also dependent on the way you application is designed.

If you are going to use any of the others modules of the lib afterwards, caching on one go (in the app initialization) should be the way to go. Which means, requiring the whole dependency.

Also I am not considering circular dependency (case where requiring *a.js* also requires *b.js*) because it is considered in most cases poor designed code (even with Node.js supporting it) and if that is happening and you do not know calling *a.js* or *b.js* will not matter because they will get called (despite your efforts for optimization) and cached anyway.